# Cannot add new file when unshelving

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, version-control

I am trying to unshelve some files in VS2010. This works perfectly, except when the file does not exist in my local workspace. When the change is "Add", it fails with the message : "The path xxx/xxxx has an incompatible pending change.".

My process is :

Get latest version recursively from server (replacing all files to ensure there's no pending changed in my workspace).
Unshelve, selecting the specific files from the shelveset that I want.

Modifications work, but adding new files fails for all of them with the above error message.

Does anybody know what might be causing this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054786/how-can-i-instruct-perforce-to-merge-instead-of-overwrite-or-revert-when-unshelv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you that you did a

> Get latest version recursively from server (replacing all files to
>   ensure there's no pending changed in my workspace)

But this would not undo an existing "Add" operation.

My guess is that if you check your workspace Pending Changes window, you will, in fact, have a pending add at that location (even though you do not necessarily have a file at that location).