# Can I re-merge one file from the previous merge in perforce?

Tags: perforce

I did a merge of bunch of files in perforce from one project into another. Turns out one of the file (VC++ .rc) file didn't merge properly and can't even open this in IDE as a result. I just want to remerge this single file again and leave the rest as is. Is this possible?

I did try 'rollback' on the file in target project but haven't checked in yet. Than I tried to re-merge/integrate just this file but it doesn't really work.

Comment: If you haven't checked in the merged files yet, have you tried reverting the file to its previous state before merging it again?

Comment: Unfortunately I have already checked in the (first) merge and hence this problem. Otherwise I could just have reverted the files and re-merge it again.

Answer (score 2):

Perforce has a couple of suggestions in their knowledgebase: http://kb.perforce.com/article/517

Essentially what you probably have to do is to "update" the .rc file to the revision prior to the failed merge (probably using rollback) and then re-integrate that file. If it mumbles something about already having been integrated you should be able to use the "force" flag (-f) for p4 integrate.

Comment: I came across a nice tip in post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054786/how-can-i-instruct-perforce-to-merge-instead-of-overwrite-or-revert-when-unshelv (the accepted answer by 'Chance') and used that technique to merge the file and it worked well.